# Last object in a list isn't deleted after deleting it. When is it effectively deleted?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

The following code should delete each of the `n` Human objects, then print the last line, but it deletes only 4 of them, the 5th gets deleted (I think) after execution stops.

```py
class Human():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __del__(self):
        print(f'{self.name} is dead')


n = 5
humans = []
for i in range(n):
    human = Human('Bob')
    humans.append(human)

for i in reversed(range(n)):
    del humans[i]

print('DEATH')
```

The output is the following (Powershell and Python 3.8.1):

```
Bob is dead  
Bob is dead  
Bob is dead  
Bob is dead  
DEATH  
Bob is dead
```

After the 2nd for-loop `humans` is empty, so it's not possible to delete the last item by `del humans[0]`. Other ways of deleting contents (`del humans[:]` or `humans.clear`) of the list also don't fix the issue, the output stays the same.

So, is this how the code should behave or is there some issue?

Comment: Try `print(humans)` in a few strategic places to see what the output is. You probably want to give them unique names so you can see what's going on.

Comment: `del` doesn't call `__del__`. `del humans[i]` just removes a list entry.

Comment: There is no way to manually delete objects in Python.

Comment: `__del__` is running when the object is garbage collected, which is sometime *after* the object is removed from the list.

Comment: It is a garbage collector side effect

Comment: The last human is still accessible through the `human` variable.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice After the first loop it shows that humans contains 5 items, after the second - 0 items. After each iteration it prints one less item and on the last iteration just []. The problem is it somehow ignores one of the items.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yes, I need __del__ to check if the item is deleted or not.

Comment: The crucial thing here is that `del humans[i]` doesn't delete the object, it just deletes it *from that list*.  The object is only deleted when nothing references it.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Only remove references, right?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Got it, thanks!

Comment: @Samwise Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the objects isn't being garbage-collected because there's still a reference to it:

```
class Human():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __del__(self):
        print(f'{self.name} is dead')


n = 5
humans = []
for i in range(n):
    human = Human(f'Bob {i}')
    humans.append(human)

for i in reversed(range(n)):
    print(f'Die, {humans[i].name}!')
    del humans[i]

print('DEATH')
print(f"(except for {human.name} whom we haven't forgotten about!)")
```

If you want to avoid that dangling reference, an easy fix is not to create it in the first place:

```
n = 5
humans = []
for i in range(n):
    humans.append(Human(f'Bob {i}'))
```

or better yet:

```
n = 5
humans = [Human(f'Bob {i}') for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: Upvoted because of all the fun you had with the messages.

Comment: Thank you! Though in the bigger code I need to instantiate these objects, now just need to figure out a way to remove all references...

Comment: Easiest way to make sure you remove all references is not to create references unnecessarily.  In the context of a larger app it's actually easier in some respects because your local variables are more likely to go out of scope before you need the objects to be cleaned up.  If the above code was in a function instead of at the top level of the module, you'd see `Bob 4` get deleted as soon as the function returned (because `human` would go out of scope at that time).

Comment: @Samwise I see... So after the function has ended, local variable human will get disposed of, and the issue I had won't appear, right?

Comment: @plane: Why does object destruction timing matter to you? If you're just worried about memory leaks, don't go around inserting manual `whatever = None` and `del some_list[i]` calls everywhere. Most objects will become unreachable naturally as variables go out of scope; it's very rare to need to manually clear references.

Comment: If object destruction timing matters to you because you've tied some important work to `__del__` methods, that work should probably not be `__del__`'s responsibility. There's no guarantee that `__del__` will *ever* run.

Comment: I'd add to that that if you want fine-grained control over your memory usage, you probably don't want to be using a garbage-collected language at all.  Trying to second guess and debug the Python memory collector is a lot harder than just writing your code in something like C++ or Rust IMO.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica @Samwise Thank you! I wanted to print each object's attributes when it's 'deleted', now I see there're better ways to do this. I'm not yet ready to dive into stuff with C++ difficulty, I used `__del__` (and this code overall) to get better understanding of classes.